# graph is distance-regular if and only if the number of $i,j$ walks of length $k$ depends only on $d(i, j)$.

Tags: algebraic-graph-theory

Show that a connected graph is distance-regular if and only if for each 
positive integer $k$, the number of $i,j$ walks of length $k$ depends only on 
$d(i, j)$.

I think I must use this relation $AA_i=b_{i-1}A_{i-1}+a_i A_i+c_{i+1}A_{i+1}$,when $G$ is distance-regular iff we have this relation.

if I put $i=k-1$ do I have walk of length $k$?if it is right,because $AA_{k-1}$ is in adjacency Algebra ,it is equal of linear combination of $A_{i}$ so it is only depend on d(i,j).

it will be great if you guide me.thanks a lot.

Comment: What is $A_i$?$ $

Comment: we define $(A_i)_{rs}$ :when $d(v_r,v_s)=i$ entry $r,s$ in matrix $A_i$ is 1,otherwise it is zero.

Comment: I think you have to study a bit of basic literature on distance-regular graphs. Try to open the book _Brouwer, Cohen, Neumaier: Distance-regular graphs_ or a newer source, which could be better for beginners in this area: _van Dam, Koolen, Tanaka: Distance-regular graphs_ which can be downloaded from the web.